# SQL or ORA exceptions caused due to invalid sql, database package state or some database exceptions

Tags: bi-publisher

I am getting the above error in **BIPublisher**'s Data model when I try to view sample data.
Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Try click the *View Engine Log* to generate the xxx.xml file. Open that file and you'll see useful information on the real error which your BIP report have.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing your SQL within another "Select * from ()"

It Worked for me.

For Ex. If your code is
`Select Sysdate From Dual`
Then make it
`Select * from (Select Sysdate From Dual)`